# Full calendar não executa arquivo PHP

Tags: php, fullcalendar

Criei uma agenda com fullcalendar utilizando o projeto deste [site](https://medium.com/@guimenegussi/criando-um-calend%C3%A1rio-de-eventos-din%C3%A2micos-com-php-ajax-e-fullcalendar-js-6cc21634b1a4), mas quando utilizo o PHP para obter os eventos do banco, não são exibidos na agenda, mas se chamo um json mostra o evento normalmente. No arquivo PHP entendi que é gerado um json, mas não sei como salvá-lo para usar. Se alguém souber o que está errado, agradeço a ajuda. Segue abaixo o código:

calendar.php

```
  <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {   

            //CARREGA CALENDÁRIO E EVENTOS DO BANCO
            $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                //defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, 
                events: 'eventos.php',          
                eventColor: '#dd6777'
            }); 
       }); 

    </script>

    <style>
        #calendario{
            position: relative;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0px auto;
        }        
    </style>

</head>
<body>    
    <div id='calendario'>
    </div>
</body>
```

eventos.php

```
<?php
  $conexao = mysqli_connect('', '', '', ''); 

    $consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT event_id, title, start, end FROM eventos"); 
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $vetor[]= "{id:{$linha['event_id']}, title: {$linha['title']}, start: {$linha['start']}, end:{$linha['end']}}";
     }
    //Passando vetor em forma de json
    echo json_encode($vetor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, alterei a conexão para o tipo PDO e o while também, após os eventos apareceram normalmente através do arquivo PHP.

```
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db', '$user', '$senha');
        $consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT event_id as id, title, start, end FROM eventos"); 
        while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
            $vetor[] = $linha;
         }
        //Passando vetor em forma de json
        echo json_encode($vetor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando um JSON "como *string*" em:

```
$vetor[]= "{id:{$linha['event_id']}, title: {$linha['title']}, start: {$linha['start']}, end:{$linha['end']}}";
```

Você tem algumas opções, uma seria utilizar:

```
$vetor[] = $linha;
```

Para isto funcionar utilize o `event_id as id`, assim será criado uma array com a chave `id` com o valor do `event_id`, *por segurança defina todas as colunas*:

```
SELECT `event_id` as `id`, `title`, `start`, `end` FROM eventos
```

Dessa forma você irá retornar uma array com exatamente todas as colunas.

---

Uma outra forma, redundante seria utilizar:

```
$vetor[] = [
   'id' => $linha['event_id'], 
   'title' => $linha['title'], 
   'start' => $linha['start'], 
   'end' => $linha['end']
];
```

---

Recomendo que veja a documentação do [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para saber como isto funciona.

Comment: Não entendo para onde vai esse json criado, eu gostaria de salvar ele paa utilizar na agenda, mas ao pesquisar não encontrei como fazer isso

Comment: O json "vai" para o cliente quando ele requisita, no primeiro código seu, você define `events: 'eventos.php',`, logo ele chama esta página. O seu servidor executa a query, monta o JSON e retorna ao `fullCalendar`, que está no lado do cliente e executa o `fullCalendar`. O problema no seu código é o erro na hora de gerar o JSON, *isto foi o que mencionei na primeira linha*.

Comment: Mas antes de usar assim, eu já havia tentado do jeito que você sugeriu, porque no site que usei de base é utilizado assim. Não funciona do jeito que você sugeriu

Comment: Você mudou a *query* para que o MySQL informe o `id` com o valor do ` `event_id`? Se não você vai criar um json contendo `event_id=1` e `id=1`, em resumo. No seu código original você tenta utilizar `id`, por isso pressuponho que ele queira o `id` e não `event_id`.

Comment: Sim, alterei o id na no chamado da query

Comment: Posso testar isto mais tarde, mas não consigo ver nenhum outro problema. Veja no F12 > Console se é apontado algum problema e também no F12 > Network se é retornado o JSON corretamente.

Comment: Ok, irei testar para ver se está retornando.